# WebRTC: Cannot do Peer to Peer connection. Browser Does not ask to Grant permission for Microphone/ Webcam

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia, peer

I am trying to make a 2 person video calling application using WebRTC. 
The code seems to be bug free, the only problem I am having is that the browser is not asking a prompt to allow for access to Webcam and Mic.

I have hosted the website [here](https://www.googledrive.com/host/0B0byAC8kZZPheFFUTkxEcXltY00/) and the relevant files are [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B0byAC8kZZPheFFUTkxEcXltY00&usp=sharing).

I have checked if the problem is not with the site and just with the Camera/ Mic, but that is not so. When I host my video. The problem is not there.

What is the problem that when I try a peer to peer Web Video call, there is no prompt for access to webcam/ Mic by the browser?

Comment: the links  in the question are empty.. please re-edit your question 
else if you found answer flag moderator to delete it ,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't included the ps-webrtc-peerjs-final.js in your index.html file. Add the line

```
<script src="ps-webrtc-peerjs-final.js"></script>
```

just after the include of peer.min.js and everything will work fine... :D

Comment: Yup, Did that and after correcting the network Proxy- It worked lovely!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using https,if your using http it will show prompt every time because of security reason,but you are using https its ask only once(means first time )